# C# timer synchronized with Datetime.Now

Tags: c#

In C# how to create a timer that synchronize with tick of system DateTime. custom timer should tick whenever the seconds change for DateTime.Now

Comment: You need to be triggered once per second, or within a certain range when the second has changed? What's the purpose?

Comment: I want to get triggered whenever the DateTime.Now.Second changes. If I start a timer with a timespan of 1 second,it won't be firing exactly when the system time changes.

Comment: You could do this with a busy wait loop, but hopefully there is a better way.

Comment: Even if you attempt something like a callback function, it won't be called exactly at the second tick. Try to sleep something like 10 ms short of your target, that should improve your accuracy to within a few ms. Increasing priority may also help to improve accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

You will find if you check some of the previous questions on SO, you are going to have a very hard time getting accuracy with your timer. Here is a small sample of previous questions:

- [Timer takes 10 ms more than interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989350/timer-takes-10-ms-more-than-interval/2989554#2989554)
- [C# Why are timer frequencies extremely off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416522/c-why-are-timer-frequencies-extremely-off/416688#416688)
- [.NET, event every minute (on the minute). Is a timer the best option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329900/net-event-every-minute-on-the-minute-is-a-timer-the-best-option/1329925#1329925)

Here is [another previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer) which may provide you some help.

Answer (score 0):

What would be your desired precision ?

If you say that 1ms is precise enough (or 10, or 100), you could always do a loop which compares the current time and one saved from the previous iteration, and start a thread when the seconds value of the current time value changes...

Answer (score 0):

You can use some schedule libraries, like Quartz.net, it provides examples and easy to use:
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

This code uses a System.Threading.Timer. It will look at the millisecond-offset the trigger is called. If the error is outside the accepted range, it will re-adjust the timer and it will correct the interval by averaging the error per tick.

```
class Program {
    const int MAX_ERROR_IN_MILLISECONDS = 20;
    const int ONE_SECOND = 1000;
    const int HALF_SECOND = ONE_SECOND / 2;

    private static System.Threading.Timer timer;

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(Tick);

        timer.Change(ONE_SECOND - DateTime.Now.Millisecond, ONE_SECOND);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int ticksSynced = 0;
    private static int currInterval = ONE_SECOND;
    private static void Tick(object s) {
        var ms = DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond;
        var diff = ms > HALF_SECOND ? ms - ONE_SECOND : ms;
        if (Math.Abs(diff) < MAX_ERROR_IN_MILLISECONDS) {
            // still synced
            ticksSynced++;
        } else {
            // Calculate new interval
            currInterval -= diff / ticksSynced;
            timer.Change(ONE_SECOND - ms, currInterval);
            Console.WriteLine("New interval: {0}; diff: {1}; ticks: {2}", currInterval, diff, ticksSynced);
            ticksSynced = 0;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ms);
    }
}
```

As you can see, you cannot trigger exactly on the second change in Windows. You can try to get close.